# Lambda Composite Join

Tags: c#, join, lambda

I'm trying to join the results from one query to filter the results of a second query.

**First Query**

```
// get the compound centre number and languageId key
var centreKeys = unitOfWork.CentreTranslationRepository.GetAll()
    .Where(w => w.Language.cuture == searchCulture || w.language_id == 1)
    .GroupBy(g => g.Centre.number)
    .Select(s =>
        new
        {
            CentreNumber = s.Key,
            LanguageId = s.Max(g => g.language_id)
        });
```

This returns results in the form of:

```
{ CentreNumber = 1589, LanguageId = 27 }

{ CentreNumber = 261, LanguageId = 1 }  

{ CentreNumber = 1257, LanguageId = 1 }

{ CentreNumber = 925, LanguageId = 1 }
```

etc

**Second Query**

```
// join onto the translated table
var centres = unitOfWork.CentreTranslationRepository.GetAll()
    .Join(centreKeys,
          centreTranslation => new { centreTranslation.Centre.number, centreTranslation.language_id },
          centreKey => new { centreKey.CentreNumber, centreKey.LanguageId },
          (centreTranslation, centreKey) =>
              new Centre
              {
                  CentreNumber = centreTranslation.Centre.number,
                  name = centreTranslation.Centre.name
                  // etc
              });
```

Performing the join with a single key works without issue, however as shown above, i'm trying to join using an anonymous composite key.

This is when I get the error:

```
Error   1   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, System.Func<TOuter,TKey>, System.Func<TInner,TKey>, System.Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.    C:\Development\SVN\Projects\CentreDirectoryService\CentreDirectoryService\Services\DomainService.cs 32  65  CentreDirectoryService
```

What am I doing wrong in the second query?

Comment: In the second query, try explicitly naming your `new` properties. That is, instead of `new { centreTranslation.Centre.number, centreTranslation.language_id }` use `new { CentreNumber = centreTranslation.Centre.number, LanguageId = centreTranslation.language_id }` (and the same for the second `new {}` on the next line. If that doesn't work, try declaring the class instead of using anonymous types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
new { centreTranslation.Centre.number, centreTranslation.language_id }
```

and this:

```
new { centreKey.CentreNumber, centreKey.LanguageId }
```

define objects of *different* anonymous types. In order for anonymous types to be unified, they need their members to have **the same names, the same types, and in the same order**. When you don't supply member names, the compiler uses the supplied expressions, so the first makes a type with members `number` and `language_id`, and the second makes a type with members `CentreNumber` and `LanguageId`.

Try changing the first one to

```
new {
        CentreNumber = centreTranslation.Centre.number, 
        LanguageId  = centreTranslation.language_id 
    }
```

(and making the necessary downstream changes).